# Какие есть альтернативы PHP для сборки вебсайта?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-сервер

В случае, если требуется простая вклейка одних header, footer и неизменных url на всех страницах сайта, какие существуют альтернвтивы PHP с его require, echo, print? (Не вызывающие проблем с SEO)

Comment: [SSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(программирование))

Comment: Не понимаю, при чём тут вообще SEO...

Comment: Например: Python, JS.

Comment: На генераторы статических сайтов взгляните. Jekyll, к примеру.

Answer (score 5):

perl,ruby,go,NodeJS,python. А вообще любой язык программирования может использоваться для работы в web (правда нужно уметь его использовать).

Comment: а еще можно gulp / grunt / webpack настроить и собирать им.

или, как вариант использовать js для подключения модулей в HTML